# How to see what applications do some actions when I power on my phone?

Tags: boot, standby, htc-incredible-s, battery-life

I believe there's some set of “hooks”, which get executed when I power on the phone. I want to see it to figure out the reason why my phone sometimes doesn't wake up properly (wakes with black screen).

Comment: best option is probably to attach to logcat when the device boots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the logcat option recommended by Ryan of course is a valid possibility, it is not the most user-friendly solution. I've got a better idea :)

Apps started automatically after boot registered for a certain event, called `BOOT_COMPLETED`. To do so, they need to request this permission (you find it under "more" on the playstore pages) called "Start after Boot" (or, with its technical name, `BOOT_COMPLETED` -- what a surprise!). So to figure out which apps could potentially be in here, you can use a permission checker. There are many of them in the Playstore, but I will mention only two of them to get you started:

- [PermissionDog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.PermissioDog)<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMCQe.jpg)</sup>
- [RL Permissions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redlicense.permissions)<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z76Cr.jpg)</sup>

[image: PermissionDog] [image: RL Permissions]

Both let you browse your apps by permissions, and even try to indicate "potentially dangerous apps" -- nice side-effect in your case ;)